# Get keyboard key name given symbol

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, keyboard-shortcuts

In a Chrome extension that I'm building, I configured a suggested key combination that opens the extension. The extension displays the shortcut with a link to chrome://extensions/shortcuts to allow users to customize the shortcut. Once a user customizes the shortcut, the extension should display the new shortcut combination instead of the default.

chrome.commands.getAll (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/commands) returns the current shortcuts for the extension. Each shortcut returned from it includes the symbol for keys that have one.

```
[
  "⌥",
  "⇧",
  "W"
]
```

Instead of displaying the symbol (e.g. ⌥), I want to display the more user-friendly key name (e.g. Alt). Is there a method that can automatically provide that?

Comment: I don't think there is any native dictionary lookup mechanism. You probably will have to create / get your own and manually do a lookup

Comment: The strings you're getting _are_ the user-friendly key symbols, and are printed on the keyboard for non-US layouts. The same format is also used in the menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. You'd have to map them yourself, for example using a big object with those strings as keys and the "user-friendly" names as values.

Comment: At that point though, you might just want to use the strings Chrome gives you. Whether it's worth it is up to you.